# How to get current year with coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I am working with Angular/CoffeeScript/Rails and I am trying to place the copyright with the current year in the footer.

With JavaScript, I used to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var theDate = new Date();
    $('.mDate').html('&copy; ' + theDate.getFullYear());
-->
</script>
<span class="mDate"></span>
```

Here is what I have tried in CoffeeScript - within the mainController.coffee:

```
  # mCopyRight
  # ------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.mCopyRight = ->
    $scope.theDate = new Date();
    $scope.mFullYear = '&copy; ' + theDate.getFullYear();
```

Within the application.html.erb

```
  <span class="mDate">{{mFullYear}}</span>
```

But nothing is showing up.

It is like new Date is not working and/or .getFullYear(); either

The only thing that I can think of, would be to make a regular js file and require it in the application.js file:

```
//= require user-defined/mDate
```

With a file named mDate.js being in the vendor/assets/javascripts/user-defined/ directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your not using the `$scope.theDate` since you stored the `Date` object on the `$scope` via the `theDate` property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned theDate to be a property of $scope. Either read it from there:

```
  $scope.mCopyRight = ->
    $scope.theDate = new Date
    $scope.mFullYear = '&copy; ' + $scope.theDate.getFullYear()
```

Or if that value is only needed by this function, don't use $scope:

```
  $scope.mCopyRight = ->
    theDate = new Date
    $scope.mFullYear = '&copy; ' + theDate.getFullYear()
```

Comment: I see your point, but when I tried this and it still does not populate {{mFullYear}} with anything

Comment: are you calling the mCopyRight function? example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IlhoDgbmmPHIsWA8cGuT

Comment: I was calling it on the p tag onload="mCopyRight()" - Your code worked. I placed the $scope.mCopyRight in the mainController.coffee file, like your example on plnkr. BTW, the &copy; had to be placed in my _footer.html.erb template file. Does this mean that coffee doesn't understand html codes? Thank you for your help

Comment: I have never tried to put an HTML encoded character in my controllers. I assume that you would have to tell angular somehow that it is an encoded string.

Comment: Updated example with the copyright symbol working: http://plnkr.co/edit/MYP1kVmQJkOHVYEMLSwb

Comment: I had never even heard of $sce before - $sce.trustAsHtml('&copy; ' - thanks again bro

Comment: Be careful with trusting any text as html that contains user input.

Comment: This isn't an input field, but I am curious as to what the issues could be - btw, I have completed the Angular/RoR project - kronusproductions.com:3000/ - total newbie at Rails